# Is there a way to hint which constructor Unity should use?

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container, constructor-injection

Unity's [`InjectionConstructor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.injectionconstructor.aspx) works well when you need to invoke a specific constructor because you have very specific dependencies in mind (e.g. any mix of external dependencies, named registrations, or unnamed registrations), but it requires *all* parameters to be specified.

Is there some way to augment Unity's "find and use the constructor with the most number of parameters" with "find and use the constructor with the most number of parameters that *also* could accept an instance of `IX` somewhere in the signature"?

Comment: I'm not aware that you can do anything like that directly, but perhaps you could derive from InjectionConstructor and override its `AddPolicies` method?

Comment: If you can, prevent a design where your service classes have more than one public constructor. This makes makes the design much cleaner and as a side effect more DI friendly.

Comment: @Steven - totally agree. I actually only have one in this case. I guess *augment* was the wrong word. Perhaps saying I needed something between *explicit* (`InjectionConstructor`) and *implicit* (not using `InjectionConstructor` at all) makes more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark's comment provided the basis for the answer. Namely, the implementation of `AddPolicies`

- has to find a constructor that matches all of the values (explicit) I pass into the constructor of `InjectionConstructor`. There are limitations (e.g. if the values are null or they get matched against a supertype in a constructor), and
- for the remaining (implicit) ones, use the container to resolve them.

I'm not saying this is good though. I ultimately used `RegisterInstance` elsewhere and the mixed-parameter need went away. But it's a solution for those who might need it.